# lxml Python package changes copyright symbol to HTML entity

Tags: python, lxml

I have a Python program that reads XML files and modifies the version attributes. Some of these files also have a copyright notice, with the copyright symbol `©`. The lxml package turns these into the HTML entity `&#169`. Is there a way to prevent this?

I tried using the `resolve_entities` parameter of the XMLParser function, but that has no effect. I've tried with both Python 2.7 and 3.6.3. The program below is for Python 3.

```
# coding: utf-8
import os
import glob
import argparse
from lxml import etree

xParser = etree.XMLParser(strip_cdata=False, resolve_entities=False)
etree.set_default_parser(xParser)

someXML ='<node version="1.0.1"><copyright>Copyright © 2017 by me</copyright></node>'

doc = etree.fromstring(someXML)

print(someXML)
print(etree.tostring(doc))
```

It prints out:

```
<node version="1.0.1"><copyright>Copyright c 2017 by me</copyright></node>
b'<node version="1.0.1"><copyright>Copyright &#169; 2017 by me</copyright></node>'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify the `unicode` encoding when dumping to string:

```
etree.tostring(doc, encoding="unicode")
```

Demo:

```
In [1]: from lxml import etree

In [2]: xParser = etree.XMLParser(strip_cdata=False, resolve_entities=False)

In [3]: someXML ='<node version="1.0.1"><copyright>Copyright © 2017 by me</copyright></node>'

In [4]: doc = etree.fromstring(someXML, parser=xParser)

In [5]: print(someXML)
<node version="1.0.1"><copyright>Copyright © 2017 by me</copyright></node>

In [6]: print(etree.tostring(doc, encoding="unicode"))
<node version="1.0.1"><copyright>Copyright © 2017 by me</copyright></node>
```

Comment: Thanks. I got the same answer when I posted the question on the lxml mailing list. I actually need to use the write function, which also has the encoding parameter.

Comment: newbie question: Is it safe to change `"utf-8"` to `"unicode"` for a whole page?